# Does multiprocessing creates a copy of a class?

Tags: python, object, multiprocessing

I am using multiprocessing in Python to run a number of tasks.

I am doing it like this:

```
    tasks = multiprocessing.JoinableQueue()
    results = multiprocessing.Queue()      

    # Start consumers

    num_consumers = multiprocessing.cpu_count() * 2
    consumers = [ Consumer(tasks, results) for _ in range(num_consumers) ]  

    for w in consumers:
        w.start()
```

And then I have an attribute "Colony" which has a list of ants, all initialized in `__init__`

```
        for ant in self.colony.ants:
            tasks.put(ant)
            num_tasks += 1
```

The thing is that when I run all the tasks (ie. The method `__call__`) is called in each ant.
I return `self` and when I compare:

```
        # We wait now for all the ants to finish 
        tasks.join() 
        results_list = list()

        for _ in range(num_tasks):
            results_list.append(results.get())

        print (id(results_list[0]),results_list[0].id)
        print(id(self.colony.ants[0]),self.colony.ants[0].id)
```

And I get

> ```
> (33524112, 0)
> (33005072, 0)
> ```

So it's the same ant, but after it's been called by the Consumer it creates a copy of itself? or am I missing something.
The ant is not instantiated anywhere else.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `Queue` pickles and unpickles objects. So yes copies are made. http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#pipes-and-queues If you want the object to keep the same id it needs to be put in shared memory http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes

Comment: Uops.. should have refer to there first. thanks so much anyway!